# Can't run angular app

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to run an angularjs page. I've only created a controller but it does not work.

I've reduced the code as much as I can to spot the problem but I can't found it, there are only two files:

`index.html`

```
<html np-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="RunmeCtrl">{{hi}}</body>
</html>
```

`main.js`

```
function RunmeCtrl($scope) {
  console.log('RUNNING!!!');
  $scope.hi="asjklfdkajsfkl";
}

console.log('script loaded');
```

The console only logs `script loaded`, but the controller is not invoked and I don't know why.
The page displays "{{hi}}" in a browser. No error shown.

Any idea?

UPDATE:

Angularjs is loading correctly since I can found `angular` object on the javascript console:

```
> angular
Object {element: function, bootstrap: function, copy: function, extend: function, equals: function…}
```

Comment: Could it be the `np-app` instead of `ng-app`?

Comment: Lol, kill me. You're right, thanks @Lukas :)

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to accept an answer so fast, I'll accept in 10 minutes, thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about typo

Comment: @Stewie it's true, is there something I can do?

Comment: Well, I guess you can always remove your question or wait for the community to remove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you need to switch `np-app` to `ng-app`. :)